# global variable not being assigned on tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, global-variables

Im working on a project where I am trying to take a directory of a file. I am having issue assigning the directory to a global variable so that ...

Here is my attempt:

```
dir = None
def print_dir(event):
    print(dir)

def main:
    root = Tk()
    def get_dir(event):
        ftypes = [('PDF',"*.pdf")]
        root.fileName = askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes)
        dir = root.fileName
        return
     btn = Button(root,   text="+  Get dir")
     btn.grid(row=3, column=6)
     btn.bind("<Button-1>", get_dir)

     btn_two = Button(root,   text="+  Print dir")
     btn_two.grid(row=3, column=6)
     btn_two.bind("<Button-1>", print_dir)

     root.mainloop()
```

None is being printed even after opening the directory file using the first button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear as to why you would define function `print_dir()` outside `main()` and function `get_dir()` inside `main()`. It makes no sense at all.

But; you assign a value to the variable `folder` inside the function `get_dir()`, that is within local scope. When you exit the function the variable is garbage collected. Python will then use the variable `folder` if it's defined in a broader scope, which it is.

This might work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

folder = None
def print_dir(event):
    print(folder)

def main():
    global folder   # Making variable "folder" global
    root = Tk()
    def get_dir(event):
        global folder   # Making variable "folder" global
        ftypes = [('PDF',"*.pdf")]
        root.fileName = askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes)
        folder = root.fileName
        return

    btn = Button(root, text="+  Get dir")
    btn.grid(row=2, column=6)
    btn.bind("<Button-1>", get_dir)

    btn_two = Button(root, text="+  Print dir")
    btn_two.grid(row=3, column=6)
    btn_two.bind("<Button-1>", print_dir)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: This is not the whole code. I am just giving part of the code

Comment: is there a way to assign the directory to the "dir" global variable

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot: don't call the variable `dir` as that is a reserved word. Im leaving a working example in an answer